# Why do I need to reference a custom gradle config with square brackets?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I created a gradle build config just to download some dependencies. The documentation has been sparse, so I've piece together this working snippet based on random snippets and guesses.

```
configurations {
    create("downloadDeps")
}

dependencies {
    // JSON
    configurations["downloadDeps"]("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3")
    configurations["downloadDeps"]("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3")
}

repositories {
    // internal repository
    maven {
        url = uri("...")
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER") ?: System.getProperty("ARTIFACTORY_USER") as String
            password = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN") ?: System.getProperty("ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN") as String
        }
    }
}

tasks.register<Copy> ("downloadDeps") {
    from(configurations["downloadDeps"])
    into("lib/")
}
```

If I reference the "downloadDeps" dependency like configuration.downloadDeps or downloadDeps("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3"). I get an error about an unresolved reference to "downloadDeps".

Why does implementation("...") or configuration.implementation.get() work?

Comment: I _think_ this addresses your question: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors

Answer (score 1):

The documentation @Slaw provided helped me understand why I can do something like this:

`implementation("group:artifact:1.0.0")`

but not

`myCustomConfig("group:artifact:1.0.0")`

`implementation` being declared that way is supported [because it comes from a plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors:%7E:text=The%20Kotlin%20DSL%20currently%20supports%20type%2Dsafe%20model%20accessors%20for%20any%20of%20the%20following%20that%20are%20contributed%20by%20plugins) (the Kotlin/Java plugins)

The simplest way to associate a dependency with `myCustomConfig` would be to do this (see [these docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_using_standard_api)):

`"myCustomConfig"("group:artifact:1.0.0")`